# Refactoring the following methods to make it easier to read

Tags: c#

Would it be possible to refactor the following methods?

If so - how would I go about best doing it?

```
    public void PlotListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PlotListView.SelectedItems.Count == 0) return;
        var selectedItem = (PlotComponent.PlotList) PlotListView.SelectedItems[0];
        _focusPlotReference = Convert.ToInt32(selectedItem.PlotId);
    }

    public void WatchListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (WatchListView.SelectedItems.Count == 0) return;
        var selectedItem = (PlotComponent.PlotList) WatchListView.SelectedItems[0];
        _focusWatchReference = Convert.ToInt32(selectedItem.PlotId);
    }

    public void PositionListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PositionListView.SelectedItems.Count == 0) return;
        var selectedItem = (PlotComponent.PlotList) PositionListView.SelectedItems[0];
        _focusPositionReference = Convert.ToInt32(selectedItem.PlotId);
    }

    private void FocusPlotItem(int focusPlotReference)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(
            (() =>
            {
                PlotComponent.PlotList plotList =
                    PlotListView.Items.OfType<PlotComponent.PlotList>()
                        .FirstOrDefault(p => Convert.ToInt32(p.PlotId) == focusPlotReference);
                if (plotList == null) return;
                //get visual container
                var container = PlotListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(plotList) as ListViewItem;
                if (container == null) return;
                container.IsSelected = true;
                container.Focus();
            }));
    }

    private void FocusWatchItem(int focusWatchReference)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(
            (() =>
            {
                PlotComponent.PlotList watchList =
                    WatchListView.Items.OfType<PlotComponent.PlotList>()
                        .FirstOrDefault(p => Convert.ToInt32(p.PlotId) == focusWatchReference);
                if (watchList == null) return;
                //get visual container
                var container = WatchListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(watchList) as ListViewItem;
                if (container == null) return;
                container.IsSelected = true;
                container.Focus();
            }));
    }

    private void FocusPositionItem(int focusPositionReference)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(
            (() =>
            {
                PlotComponent.PlotList positionList =
                    PositionListView.Items.OfType<PlotComponent.PlotList>()
                        .FirstOrDefault(p => Convert.ToInt32(p.PlotId) == focusPositionReference);
                if (positionList == null) return;
                //get visual container
                var container =
                    PositionListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(positionList) as ListViewItem;
                if (container == null) return;
                container.IsSelected = true;
                container.Focus();
            }));
    }
```

Comment: It is probably possible, but it would be easier if we would know what your code do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those three event handlers repeat a lot of code, which should be extracted into a method:

```
private int GetPlotId(object sender)
{
    var listView = sender as ListView;
    if(listView == null || listView.SelectedItems.Count == 0) 
        return int.MinValue;

    return ((PlotComponent.PlotList) PositionListView.SelectedItems[0]).PlotId;
}
```

(You might even want to add even more checks, or perhaps remove some.)

They can then be rewritten like this:

```
public void PlotListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var plotId = GetPlotId(sender);
    if(plotId == int.MinValue)
       return;

    _focusPlotReference = plotId ;
}
```

Perhaps this could be improved further, but I don't have a VS ready at the moment. Which is also why I won't be tackling the second set of methods right now.

---

I don't know what a `PlotList` is, but since it seems to be a single item, I don't feel `List` is a good name for it.

I'm also not sure why you'd need to add the namespace to the class explicitly: `PlotComponent.PlotList`. That's usually a red flag for me.

---

Could you also indicate what kind of project this is? I'm guessing Windows Forms, but it would be useful to get a little more context.